# Disk Node vs Ram Node in RabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq

I googled about it and after read some article and ebook Learning RabbitMQ, i didnt understand  the exact differences, in [Article](https://www.cnblogs.com/popsuper1982/p/3800419.html) i read that is Disk Node the related meta Data stored in Disk and Ram too, and in Ram Node only stored on Ram. but in Ebook doesnot say something like this, Disk Node only stored metadata on Disk and Ram Node only stored on Ram! which one is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about RAM nodes. Only use disk nodes - they store data on disk and in RAM.